# Append on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email

I'm trying to append some items after the contact form is submitted. Unfortunately, I don't know how to tell it what document to append the items to. Here is the full code. Someone able to help?

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'contact@jeremyblaze.com';
$subject = 'Support Request';

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").append("<p class='success'>Thanks! Your email has been sent.</p>");
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").append("<p class='error'>Sorry, something has gone wrong.</p>");
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't solve your problem, however it's far better to use server-side validation/checking instead of Javascript. Javascript can be disabled.

Comment: @Fred Thanks. I'll have a look at that instead :)

Comment: "I don't know how to tell it what document to append the items to." That doesn't make a lot of sense. It can only append it to the document the code runs on.

Comment: Are you posting the form to the same page? or is this above a completely seperate page?

Comment: check my answer if might help you ...!!
$("#submit") --> refer to submit button ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. I can't tell if this is a jquery/javascript or php question. Document refers to the page you're on. Just put whatever your form id is in here --->`$('#formIdGoesHere')` and call the append.

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/NYac5/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#submit").after("<p class='error'>Sorry, something has gone wrong.</p>");
 });
```

Comment: Why is `.after()` any better than `.append()`?

Comment: he is trying to append paragraph in Submit button which is not possible.So i used after which means after the Submit button place this paragraph. append can be used with div,span,p etc. elements which can contain elements.

Comment: How do you know `#submit` is a button when he hasn't listed his HTML?

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing. Maybe he calls his form `#submit`

Comment: i am just according to the naming convention ..!!

Answer (score 0):

This section of code is mixing PHP, HTML and Javascript - it won't work like this.

```
if ($mail_status) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  .
  .
  .
  </script>
<?php
```

You need to do one of two things. Either emit a new document with the mail status, or send a response back to an Ajax call (if you've done things that way)

E.g.

```
if ($mailStatus) {
?>
<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>
  <p class='success'>Thanks! Your email has been sent.</p>
</body></html>
<?php } else {  ?>
<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>
  <p class='failure'>Sorry! Your mail couldn't be sent</p>
</body></html>
<?php }
```

...or...

```
if ($mailStatus) {
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  echo '{"errcode":"0","errmsg":"Success - your message was sent"}'
} else {  
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  echo '{"errcode":"99","errmsg":"Sorry - your message couldn't be sent."}'
<?php }
```

Comment: The way you have structured your code, the form has been submitted in order for the mail to be sent. Conditional on the result of that you're emitting just a small script that will append a message to the form after it's submitted. It has already been submitted - that's why your code is running. You can't emit more HTML to a page after a submit has occurred. Either you start on a new page, or you use a an AJAX call to send the data and react to the response without a reload.

Comment: How do you know that he's not posting back to the same page?

Comment: His snippet is described as 'the full code' There's no HTML form there. Even if he is posting to the same document there's no need for jQuery to write up a message.